# How to create product with variants using Shopware 6 API

Tags: python-3.x, shopware

I need to create a batch of products with variants for Shopware 6 platform

Shopware v6.4.6.0 Version

I found [This API DOC](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/store-api/b3A6ODI2NTY4MQ-fetch-a-list-of-products), but I see only endpoints to get products but not to create them.

is there any API to create products?
or maybe there is python lib/sdk for it (haven't found it as well :( )

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the Store-API of shopware 6, which is not to be used for administrative purposes.

Use the [Admin-API](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/YXBpOjEyMjgzNTQ4-endpoints) of shopware 6 instead.
How to handle Product Data is also described in the [documentation](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUy-product-data)

Comment: could you please provide example of call/reques I need to use to create product, and product variantS?

Comment: In the admin there is a Generate Variants button - is this sufficient for you in principle? If you, I suggest to have a look at the browser's network tab when excuting the action manually to get real-life examples of the necessary requests.